# Laravel 5: Count product by category where active product only

Tags: laravel, count

In Laravel 5.4, I have my relationship:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

And my query is:

```
$x = Category::with('products')->where('active', 1)->get();
```

It does show all category names correctly, but how to count only product 'active = 1'? I don't wish to count all products, but active products only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$x = Category::with(['products' => function($query) { $query->where('active','=', 1); }])->where('active', 1)->get();
```

That will give you products that are active and then only categories where products are active.

Comment: Great! It just works the way I want. Thank you, kambythet

Comment: Between this way and select join two tables, which one performs the best?

Comment: A join will perform better generally speaking as long as your indexes exist, column Charset & collation are identical between the two (for text-based columns).  This is because of the database optimizer.  When using the laravel methods as noted herein, two queries get executed instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to be more specific. Additional from idea of @linuxartisan

```
$x = Category::whereHas('products', function ($query) {
         $query->where('products.active', '=', 1);
     })
     ->where('categories.active', '=', 1)
     ->get();
```

Comment: Works well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have `active` field for **product** as well as **category**.

Just try this query

```
$x = Category::whereHas('products', function ($query) {
     $query->where('products.active', 1);
})->where('categories.active', 1)
->get();
```

Comment: I tried it but not working. The problem is that it shows only one category, and counts all product, even active field = '0'.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class)->where('active',1);
}
```

This is working in Laravel 7